# Multiple conditions in if statement - first is always true

Tags: java, if-statement

Why is the first `if` statement always true?

```
private String setDepartment (){
   int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Department Code:\n" +
            "1:Sales\n" +
            "2:Development\n" +
            "3:Accounting\n" +
           "4:None"));

    /*Why this if statement is always true? How do i solve it? */
    if (code !=1 || code !=2 || code !=3 || code !=4)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Number.Enter a number between 1-4");
        setDepartment();
    }

    if (code==1){
        return "Sales";
    }
    else if (code==2){
        return "Development";
    }
    else if (code==3){
        return "Accounting";
    }
    else
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to learn about the switch statement here.

Comment: Because at any point of time code value would be any of 1-4. And 3 of 4 conditions would always be true.  Change your if condition to

Answer (score 1):

Replace `||` with `&&`:

```
if (code !=1 && code !=2 && code !=3 && code !=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AND instead of OR.

If the user enters 1 then it's automatically different than 2,3 and 4.

You can therefore use :

```
if (code !=1 && code !=2 && code !=3 && code !=4)
```

OR

```
if (code ==1 || code ==2 || code ==3 || code ==4)
```

Answer (score 0):

From first principles, picking `code = 1`:

```
  code !=1 || code !=2 || code !=3 || code !=4
= 1    !=1 || 1    !=2 || 1    !=3 || 1    !=4
= false    || true     || true     || true
= true
```

You probably meant `&&` rather than `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Because at any point of time code value would be any of 1-4. And 3 of 4 conditions would always be true. Change your if condition to

```
If( !( code ==1 || code == 2 || code == 3 || code == 4))
```